# How to Change the position of error alert in React JS

Tags: reactjs, toast

I am using `react alert` for displaying the error message on the frond end page , I am using `react alert template` for the printing the error and success messages

My front end page have 3 different section and I want that each error and success message should specifically print in that section , therefore I have to change the position of the error message

Any leads how to change the position of those error and success message

I tried with inline css but got no success

here is my sample code i want to change the position of the error messages 
currently the positon is `BOTTOM_CENTER`

https://codesandbox.io/s/l2mo430lzq

Comment: Have you checked this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-alert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the section: "Showing alerts in different positions at the same time " in https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-alert.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import 
`import { positions } from 'react-alert'`

And after

`const options = {
  // you can also just use 'bottom center'
  position: positions.BOTTOM_CENTER,
  timeout: 5000,
  offset: '30px',
  // you can also just use 'scale'
  transition: transitions.SCALE
}`

And in you wrapper:
`<AlertProvider {...options}>`

As response to your question says, you should check https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-alert